# Preload list into Backbone JS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js

I am trying to develop an application that will load a list of items on a page. Each item needs to be an individual model in order to track the respective attributes. So far I haven't been able to do this successfully in razor, as the list has loaded, but comes back empty on postback. I figured that backbone.js would help in this endeavour, but I have only been able to create a list, adding and deleting items on the fly, not preload them persay. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Using Backbone, it's recommended (in the docs) to load all models (for a collection) by bootstrapping them into place. For example, you could add a script tag to your html that does the following:

```
<script>
  var People = new Backbone.Collection;
  People.reset([{name: "Chris", age:30}, {name: "Josie", age: 27});
  var Projects = new Backbone.Collection;
  Projects.reset([{name: "Programming", due: "Monday"}, {name: "Cleaning", due: "Today"}]);
</script>
```

...from the Backbone docs, modified: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap

Alternately, you could fetch() the contents (sends ajax request):

```
<script>
  var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/people"
  })
  People.fetch()
</script>
```

Comment: ok, i see where you're going. However, my list will be pulled down from the server in the controller. How would I load this list into the Backbone. I think I need a JSON call, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I edited the answer to be more general. Ensure your collection declares a "url" property, and just call collection.fetch(). Backbone will make the ajax call for you (requires jQuery), and reset the collection.

Comment: In the [Collection.reset() documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset) there is an explicit example of how to bootstrap a collection during initial page load, in a Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Windows world, but one possible way of preloading is to simply get the server to write the list in script tags like

```
<script>
  window.myApp.myList = [
     { name: 'fred' },
     { name: 'mary' }
  ]
</script>
```

Then you can load that list with backbone code inline or in file:

```
var people = new PeopleCollection(window.myApp.myList)
```

Hope that is clear enough.